# Вопрос по рифмам и фонетике

Tags: фонетика

Как определить, что слово является рифмой к другому слову? Чем отличается хорошая рифма от плохой? Существует ли литература на эту тему?

Comment: Я рекомендую читать огромное количество поэзии. В том числе Маяковского и Набокова. У Маяковского есть заметка "Как писать стихи" - тоже забавно познакомиться.  Но мне всё-таки кажется, что научиться рифмовать "по рецепту" не получится.  См. напр. творчество Афанасия Фета.

Answer (score 2):

Проще ответить на обратный вопрос: как отличить *плохую рифму от хорошей*. Если взять первый попавшийся пример домашних стихов (в адрес передачи "Поле чудес" и т.п.), можно заметить, что, несмотря на рифмованность окончаний через строку и разборчивость смысла, чего-то не хватает. Дело в неупорядоченности количества слогов и/или в неудачном распределении ударения между ними; встречаются неудачные стечения согласных на стыках слов, в результате строки не складываются в общую, условно говоря, "мелодию". Она настолько важна, что удачные её образцы эксплуатируется многими авторами во многих произведениях многие столетия (это не считается плагиатом или самоплагиатом). Строки, подчинённые такой мелодии, складываются в стихи подобно пазлу, легко читаются и поются. В этом смысле, "вот кто-то с горочки спустился" - тайное заимствование от "у лукоморья дуб зелёный". Пример коллажа из строк, принадлежащих одной из распространённых "мелодий" (по 9 слогов в строках 1,3 и по 8 слогов в строках 2,4):

```
Шаланды, полные кефали, -
В тумане моря голубом;
Мой дядя - самых честных правил -
Всё ходит по цепи кругом.
```

*("Узник рыбнадзора", 2015)*

Answer (score 2):

В классическом значении, рифма - это совпадение звуков от ударного до конца строфы. Если совпадают все эти звуки, то рифма называется точной, если только часть - неточной. Если у рифмы совпадает последний предударный звук, то такая рифма называется глубокой, соответственно, если не совпадает - неглубокая. Правда бывают неточные неглубокие и тем не менее рифмы.

Ещё рифмы бывают отглагольные (состоящие из одинаковых частей речи в одной форме) и каламбурные (на основе игры слов). Первые, как правило, считаются не очень хорошими, и их избыток в стихотворении выглядит плохо, вторые чаще всего наоборот.

Только все эти знания вряд ли помогут написать хорошее стихотворение, где рифма хоть и важная, но всё же далеко не единственная составляющая.

Comment: Спасибо за столь развёрнутый комментарий. Если можете посоветовать хорошую литературу по рифмам и стихосложению, буду весьма признателен.

Answer (score 1):

Литературы масса. Начиная с Википедии (в статьях рифма, стихосложение и т.л.) и кончая, например, Гаспаровым.
Но беда в том, что все эти вещи - субъективны. 
Хорошей рифмой, напрмер, считается точная (омофоническая), неродственная, неглагольная... Неизбитая еще.

И тут же находим у Пушкина:
*Когда не в шутку **занемог**

...

И лучше выдумать **не мог**.*

Все относительно. Самая хорошая рифма плоха, если она рвет стиль стиха. Что хорошо горлану Маяковскому, то плохо Бальмонту с его кристальной чистотой созвучий. И наоборот: мелодию для клавесина Бальмонта не сыграть на трубах Маяковского. Так и тут.

Короче, хорошая рифма - это та рифма, которую используют хорошие поэты.
Для первого знакомства достаточyо, думаю.

Comment: А что из Гаспарова посоветуете на свой вкус?

Comment: Из Гаспарова? Все. Не ошибётесь. ))) Вот даю по википедии, у меня точной атрибутики нет. **Очерк истории русского стиха. Метрика, ритмика, рифма, строфика. М., Наука. 1984. 319 с. 6300 **. Не мой профиль, поэтому не могу точно дать от себя. Но вообще обожаю как автора.

Answer (score 1):

Как определить, что слово является рифмой к другому слову? — Смотреть в словаре. Чем отличается хорошая рифма от плохой? — Хорошая рифма взята не в словаре. Существует ли литература на эту тему? — Да. Хорошие Стихи.